# Springdoc - override autogenerated Schema for EntityModel

Tags: java, spring-boot, springdoc

I'm working on a Spring Boot application (in Java), currently on the backend part and I'm trying to prepare the OpenAPI spec using Springdoc.

I have this one issue that I wanted to clarify what data is returned by an endpoint returning `EntityModel<>` object. By default (excluding the Schema of my model) the example JSON generated by Springdoc looks like this:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "Spaghetti Bolognese",
  "description": "Traditional Italian recipe for Bolognese sauce",
  "source": "My grandma",
  "_links": {
    "additionalProp1": {
      "href": "string",
      "hreflang": "string",
      "title": "string",
      "type": "string",
      "deprecation": "string",
      "profile": "string",
      "name": "string",
      "templated": true
    },
    "additionalProp2": {
      "href": "string",
      "hreflang": "string",
      "title": "string",
      "type": "string",
      "deprecation": "string",
      "profile": "string",
      "name": "string",
      "templated": true
    },
    "additionalProp3": {
      "href": "string",
      "hreflang": "string",
      "title": "string",
      "type": "string",
      "deprecation": "string",
      "profile": "string",
      "name": "string",
      "templated": true
    }
  }
}
```

And the thing that I want to change is the `_links` node as I know exactly what links are returned and that I only provide the `href` property for them so the rest is just cluttering the example. I would like for the `_links` node to look something like that:

```
"_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "http://example.com/recipes/{id}"
    },
    "recipes": {
        "href": "http://example.com/recipes"
    },
    "ingredients": {
        "href": "http://example.com/recipes/{id}/ingredients"
    }
}
```

Do you know how I can achieve that?

Only way I came up with is to create my own `RecipeResponse` class that would return the Recipe model and links that I want it to return but I think that sort of kills the purpose of using Spring Boot